# Is there way to indicate a message as a reply message to another message rather than using reply() method in MimeMessage class

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I want to send a message as a reply to a another message using javax.mail api. I can't preserve original message. Therefore, I can't use 
    Message replyMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    replyMessage = (MimeMessage) Originalmessage.reply(false);

But,I can preserve all headers of original message. Is there way to mark a message as a reply to an another message using headers or else using javax.mail api.

Comment: Show the code you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what the reply method does:

> The "Subject" field is filled in with the original subject prefixed with "Re:" (unless it already starts with "Re:"). The "In-Reply-To" header is set in the new message if this message has a "Message-Id" header. The ANSWERED flag is set in this message. The current implementation also sets the "References" header in the new message to include the contents of the "References" header (or, if missing, the "In-Reply-To" header) in this message, plus the contents of the "Message-Id" header of this message, as described in RFC 2822.

Comment: Thank you very much Bill Shannon. Yes, If we set the headers of the reply message as in reply() method in Mimemessage class we can create the reply message.